# How to syncronize order of chained jQuery promised

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm chaining 3 ajax requests with to a RESTful endpoint:

1. PUT some data (return {} and OK)
2. GET the data I just put
3. show data

I've set up a chain of promises using `.then()`. But the request does not happen in the expected order (1,2,3) but rather (2,1) and starting with a `OPTIONS`request.

**Why are they not happening in the expected order?**

**How can I ensure the correct sequential order?**

```
var _id = x;

function doReqs() {
  putData(_id, data)
    .then(getData(_id))
    .then(showData);
}

// returns empty object {}
function putData(id, data) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: http://xxx,
    contentType: 'application/json'
  });
}

// returns JSON {"data": {"xx": "xx}}
function getData(id) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: http://xxx
  });
}

function showData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130327/discussion-on-question-by-olefrank-how-to-syncronize-order-of-chained-jquery-pro).

Comment: How do I access the chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
function doReqs() {
  putData(_id, data)
    .then(getData(_id))
    .then(showData);
}
```

The `.then(getData(_id))` part is just wrong.  It's wrong for two reasons.

1. `.then()` is supposed to be passed a function reference.  When you pass `getData(_id)`, you are executing that function immediately and passing the return value from that function (which is a jqXHR object) to `.then()`.  That's not what you're supposed to pass to `.then()`.
2. Because you're executing `getData(_id)` IMMEDIATELY, it will not execute properly in the promise chain sequence.

Remember, any time you pass a `func()` with the parens after it as an argument, it executes that function immediately and passes it's return value as the argument.  That is NOT what you want with `.then()` for the above reasons.

If you're trying to control what is being passed to `getData()`, then you can either make sure the right thing is returned from `putData()` because that's what will be passed to `getData()` or you can make a stub function that will pass the right thing:

```
function doReqs() {
  putData(_id, data)
    .then(function() {
        return getData(_id);
    })
    .then(showData);
}
```

Or, you could do it this way:

```
function doReqs() {
  putData(_id, data)
    .then(getData.bind(null, _id))
    .then(showData);
}
```

---

Or, since the resolved value of `putData()` is what will be passed as an argument to the next step in the promise chain (which is `getData`), you could do this:

```
function putData(id, data) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: http://xxx,
    contentType: 'application/json'
  }).then(function() {
    // make sure putData passes the id to the next step in the chain
    return id;
  });
}

function doReqs(id) {
  putData(id, data)
    .then(getData)
    .then(showData);
}
```

---

Here's a working example of chaining in action:

```js
function delay(t, val) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, val), t);
   });
}

function first(arg) {
    console.log("running first..., arg = ", arg);
    return delay(500, 10);
}

function second(arg) {
    console.log("running second..., arg = ", arg);
    return delay(100, 100);
}

function third(arg) {
    console.log("running third..., arg = ", arg);
}

first(1).then(second).then(third);
```

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation. Especially about how and what to pass on in `.then(xx)`. I now understand how to fix the order of execution of the ajax reqs. I ended up using the last of your suggestions returning id in a `.then()` on putData().